# GetEvent<SetObjectEvent> could not be found (missing directive/reference?) - what am I doing wrong ..?

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism, eventaggregator

While trying to build an eventaggregator to have the properties of my `object` be transfered from `MainViewModel` to `SectionViewModel` I've tried following multiple articles ([1](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/), [2](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23314.using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models.aspx), [3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) and  [4](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/591221/Simple-EventAggregator-in-WPF-PRISM) ) as to how this works, but I seem to be missing a step..?

In the `MainViewModel` I have;

```
protected readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
public MainViewModel(IMainViewModel mainViewModel, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
    ...Some other Code...
    this.eventAggregator = eventAggegator;
}

public Object Object
{
    ...Getter...
    set
    {
        this.object = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged();
        this.EventAggregator.GetEvent<SetObjectEvent<Object>>().Publish(this.Object);
    }
}
```

and in the `SectionViewModel` I have;

```
protected readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
public SectionViewModel(ISectionViewModel sectionViewModel, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
    this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;;
    this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<SetObjectEvent<Object>>().Subscribe((object) => { this.Object = object; });
}
```

Whom both throw the argument excpetion `The type or namespace name 'SetObjectEvent<>' could not be found`. I thought this was because I needed a global EventAggregator but someone pointed out this is not the case.

*This is the giste of most of the articles, which (to me at least) does not look like it's causing any problems. It all seems pretty logical to me, and I understand what it's supposed to do. However, none of the articles seem to actually be defining the 'SetObjectEvent' `Event`? Instead the create some sort of general `EventAggregate` and that's it. That's where I kind of lose track on what's happening. To me it sounds pretty logical I'll need to have a class something like 'Events' that can hold all the different callable events in the project, but I'd have no idea as to how to accomplish this ?*

Edit; As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39446581/4540978) implied that what I think is wrong is not the problem, I rephrased my question to more accurately (?) describe my problem.

Edit; As requested the SetObjectEvent class

```
public class SetObjectEvent<TRequest> : PubSubEvent<SetObjectEvent<TRequest>> where TRequest : IObject {}
```

derived from [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017900/prism-eventaggregator-getevent-subscribe-using-generics-contraints)

Edit; changing it to

```
public class SetObjectEvent : PubSubEvent<Object> {}
```

as suggested in multiple comments gives me the same argument exception on both `GetEvent<SetObjectEvent>()` and `GetEvent<SetObjectEvent<Object>>()`

Comment: Can you copy paste your SetObjectEvent class and tell us where it is defined?

Comment: @Igor edited it into the main post

Comment: Seemingly it should be `public class SetObjectEvent: PubSubEvent<object> {}`

Comment: @dvorn gives me the same argument exception as before, updated mainpost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As turns out, the problem was **where** (and just a little bit how*)

I had the SetObjectEvent placed in the models directive because I figured it was a model for the Event. I assumed it'd be referenced properly with `using MyProject.MyModule.Models;` within the `MainViewModel` namespace. Turns out I was wrong while browsing some more SO articles regarding the EventAggragator. The `SetObjectEvent` should be sitting in the module namespace as `namespace MyProject.MyModule.SetObjectEvent`.

> *Seemingly it should be public class SetObjectEvent: PubSubEvent {} – dvorn

Answer (score -1):

The EventAggregator class does all this for you. Internally, it has "events" dictionary

Comment: I'm getting the `The type or namespace name 'SetObjectEvent<>' could not be found` upon compiling. I know this is because as of now I don't have any instance of EventAggregator being instantiated, but after having it in an ApplicationServices class it gave me the same, though it 'promised' to resolve the issue not having an IoC container.

Comment: How you defined your event SetObjectEvent?  You should derive from `PubSubEvent<TPayload>`.  See https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Documentation/WPF/70-CommunicatingBetweenLooselyCoupledComponents.md#creating-and-publishing-events