# A PubSubEvent for methods?

Tags: c#, prism, eventaggregator

[In a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39446466/geteventsetobjectevent-could-not-be-found-missing-directive-reference-wha) I built an `event` class, `public class SetObjectEvent : PubSubEvent<MyObject> { }`, which is working perfectly fine. However, I want to do the same with methods now, so I'll have to extend something else than `PubSubEvent<>`(?)

While browsing through le bigue o'le interwebz, most question like "How do I call a method from another ViewModel through this ViewModel", people refer to dependencies or commands, which are fine solutions I've used in the past. But in this specific case, neither of those work because I'm dealing with a case where the Child of it's Parent's Sibling needs to be called **by** said Sibling. Because the Parent does not (and can not) know of it's child's existance other than the child calling for some properties every now and then, I figured using an EventAggregator would be the best possible solution, unless someone has a better idea of course.

So, Concretely, my question is; **With what should I replace `PubSubEvent<>` in my `SetObjectEvent` to get the similar version `CallMethodEvent : ?x?x?x? { }`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I completely understand your problem, because the solution is a bit trivial:

```
EventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>().Subscribe( MyMethod );
```

with

```
public class MyEvent : PubSubEvent
{
}
```

This executes `MyMethod` each time `MyEvent` is published, isn't that what the whole event mechanism is for?

I guess, you could also publish a method as payload, if you want to execute a method defined by the publisher in the context of each subscriber, but I haven't come up with a use case for that yet :-)

Comment: The problem with what you're doing is that `PubSubEvent` is not a valid argument. There is only `PubSubEvent<TPayLoad>`, which is why I'm throwing around a dummy string as proclaimed in my self-answer.

Comment: Which version of Prism do you use? Version 6.2 has a parameterless `PubSubEvent`, if you use an older version, you can't avoid the dummy parameter...

Comment: That was the problem, I was still running 6.1. Updated to 6.2 and works flawlessly, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I've created a (temporary) workaround to tackle the problem for now;

By creating the exact same set-up but with a string, `CallMethodEvent : PubSubEvent<string> { }`, I can call the desired methods by publishing, `this.EventAggregator.GetEvent<CallMethodEvent>().Publish("SomeUselessString");`, and after subscribing, `this.EventAggregator.GetEvent<CallMethodEvent>().Subscribe((someString) => { this.MethodToBeCalled(); });`, the desired method is called. The major drawback here is that there is always a string tossed around for literally no other reason than to 'make it work'. If no other answer'll pop up I'll have to stick with it, but I'd prefer a cleaner way to resolve the issue ..