# Dynamicly assign pub/subs of different event types to multiple aggregator

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, publish-subscribe, eventaggregator

I have various Modules which can send and receive different `Event<T>` . for example

```
class A : ISub<Event<Picture>>
class B : ISub<Event<SomeObject>>
class C : IPub<Event<Picture>>
...
```

etc.

Is there a proper way (existing framework) to dynamicly assign instances of these classes to different instances of `EventAggregator<T>`? For example by registering the pub/subs to a non generic EventController which then handles the connections between the modules independenly and makes it somehow easy to manage from wpf(ViewModel)?

Answer (score 0):

May be You can create one interface and inherit that interface for all your classes.

Example

[Prism - EventAggregator.GetEvent<>.Subscribe() - Using Generics & Contraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017900/prism-eventaggregator-getevent-subscribe-using-generics-contraints)

Comment: I want to be able to have multiple instances of the same Type of EventAggregator<T> and a way to register each pub sub instance independantly and then manage the connection to the different EventAggregator.